# Tkinter: How to show next frame in tuple

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a method for a tkinter button that will iterate through a tuple of frames and display the next frame whenever I click the next button.  The goal is to write the function so that I only have to pass ‘self’ (for the current visible frame object) as an argument.

I have already looked through a few examples that allow me to switch to the new frame by passing it as an argument to a function.  I currently have implemented something along these lines as a stopgap until I can figure out a solution to the current problem.  I wasn't sure how much code to include but I've paired it down so that it should still function with minimal issues.

The tuple App.frames and the else block in App.next_frame() are the problem areas.

```
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()

        #### Add any new pages to this tuple ####
        self.frames = (StartPage, Page2)
        self.current_frame = None
        self.next_frame(self.current_frame)

    def next_frame(self, cframe_class):
        '''Set the visible page to the next frame in the frames tuple.
        Pass self to the cframe_class argument'''
        if self.current_frame == None:
            '''If the application has just started, this block will run
            in order to set the current frame to the start page.'''
            self.current_frame = StartPage(self)
            self.current_frame.pack()
        else:         ##### Problem #####
            cfi = self.frames.index(cframe_class)
            #### "ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple" ####
            cfi += 1
            self.current_frame.destroy()
            self.current_frame = self.frames[cfi]
            self.current_frame.pack()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        tk.ttk.Button(self, text = "Test Next",
                        command = lambda: master.next_frame(self)).pack()

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        tk.ttk.Label(self, text = "This is Page 2").pack()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()    #app.mainloop() or root.mainloop()?

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The debugger throws **"ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple"** on the cfi variable line.  When I step through the function after clicking on the next button, the debugger tells me that my argument ‘cframe_class’ has an id of:

```
<__main__.StartPage object .!app.!startpage>
```

I understand the first part of the line, but I’m unsure about how to interpret the **object.!app.!startpage>** portion.  It looks like this should be read: 'Startpage is an object that inherits from NOTapp, NOTstartpage,' but I don't understand why that would be the case.

The StartPage object in my tuple has an id of:

```
<class '__main__.StartPage'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use an index stored as an attribute to keep track on the current frame instead of passing an argument.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.cfi = 0
        #### Add any new pages to this tuple ####
        self.frames = (StartPage(self), Page2(self))
        self.current_frame = None
        self.next_frame()

    def next_frame(self):
        '''Set the visible page to the next frame in the frames tuple.
        Pass self to the cframe_class argument'''
        if self.cfi == 0:
            '''If the application has just started, this block will run
            in order to set the current frame to the start page.'''
            self.current_frame = self.frames[0]
            self.current_frame.pack()
            self.cfi +=1
        else:
            self.current_frame.pack_forget()
            try:
                self.current_frame = self.frames[self.cfi]
            except IndexError:
                self.current_frame = self.frames[0]
                self.cfi = 0
            self.current_frame.pack()
            self.cfi += 1

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        tk.Button(self, text = "Test Next", command = master.next_frame).pack()

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        tk.Button(self, text = "This is Page 2",command=master.next_frame).pack()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()    #app.mainloop() or root.mainloop()?

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hey Henry, thanks for the reply and the solution.  I think I was also able to figure out from your code why I was getting the error where the names were not matching as well.  The tuple I created only contained the name of the base class instead of instantiating an object of the class like you did in your solution: StartPage(self).  Thanks again!